# Pythonでマウスとキーボードの現物をロックしたい（ただしpyautoguiは使えるように）

Tags: python, python3, windows, winapi

Windows、Python3.7で、指定座標（テキストボックス）をクリックし、そこにUSBバーコードリーダーから取得した文字列を送信するコードを書いています。

ただし、そのテキストボックスがあるのはリモートデスクトップ先なので、テキストボックス自体のハンドルは取得できません。
（リモート先は顧客の中にあるので、そこにはアプリを入れれません。）

そこで、リモートデスクトップを最前面アクティブにし、その画面をクリックし、pyautogui.typewriteで文字を送信することにしました。

その結果、9割がた目的通りできているものの、現物のマウスが少しでも動くと座標がずれてしまうため、文字送信位置がずれてしまいます。

そこで、文字送信時にUSBマウスとキーボードだけを一時的に無効化できる方法を探しています。

いろいろググりました中で見つかったのは、「pyusbを使う方法」と「c++でwin32apiをたたく方法」です。

pyusbを使う方法
https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb

c++でwin32apiをたたく方法
http://black-yuzunyan.lolipop.jp/archives/2487

pyusbのほうは使い方がよくわかりませんでした。
c++のほうは、これをPythonから呼び出す方法を検討していますが、ラップする方法がわからないので、使うのを躊躇しています。

今回教えていただきたいのは、Pythonのライブラリ等だけで上記目的を達成できる方法はないのか、ということです。

---

#### 実際のコード (一部を抜粋)

```
import pyautogui as gui

def mojisousin(self, mojiretu,mojisousinmaeMachiByosu:float):
    WM_CHAR = 0x0102  # テキスト（1文字）送信

    logger.info("文字送信開始")
    time.sleep(mojisousinmaeMachiByosu)  # 文字送信まち秒数

    try:
        gui.moveTo(self.x, self.y, 0)
        gui.doubleClick(self.x, self.y)
        gui.typewrite(mojiretu)  # ハンドルが無い場合は、win32guiでカーソル位置に文字送信

        logger.info("ハンドル無しでの文字送信正常完了="+str(mojiretu))
        return True
    except:
        logger.error("文字送信失敗！" + str(mojiretu))
        return False
```

Comment: 「pyusbを使う方法」で何をやろうとしているか分かりませんが、少なくとも「c++でwin32apiをたたく方法」に記載されているAPIを使うのは止めた方が良いでしょう。記事の仕組みは物理的にデバイスのUSBケーブルをPCのコネクタから抜き差しする現象をソフトウェア的にシミュレートして発生させる方法です。こちらの [boppreh/keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) か [ethanhs/PurepyHook.py](https://gist.github.com/ethanhs/80f0a7cc5c7881f5921f) あたりのLowLevelHookを更に応用して何かする方が、まだ現実的でしょう。ただしこの [How to disable then re-enable keyboard/mouse in Python 3.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55681301/9014308) のコメント内容に注意してください。希望している機能そのものがPyAutoGUIと衝突するかもしれません。

Comment: kunif様、ありがとうございます。
boppreh/keyboard試してみましたが、やはりPyAutoGUIと衝突して正常に動作しません。
「c++でwin32apiをたたく方法」にチャレンジしているところですが、このAPIを使うのは危険なのでしょうか？

Comment: OSのデバイス認識情報を操作する方式なので、実際に無効状態になるまで時間がかかるし、有効状態になるタイミングを制御出来ません。また無効にならなかったり逆に有効にならなかったりする可能性も高いですね。有効にならない場合は物理的なUSBの抜き差しが必要になります。

Comment: kunif様、わかりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: この辺の記事で扱われている名称や内容のサービスを使えば、RDPセッションを利用した独自の通信チャネルで、マウスポインタやキーボードフォーカスに頼らないリモート入力が出来そうな感じです。調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [Remote Desktop Services virtual channels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-virtual-channels), [Using Remote Desktop Services virtual channels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/using-terminal-services-virtual-channels), [Dynamic Virtual Channels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/dynamic-virtual-channels)

Comment: kunif様、いつもありがとうございます。すみません。初めの説明で簡単にリモートデスクトップと書きましたが、正確にはExceed onDemandClientというソフトで取引先のUNIXにVPN経由で接続しています。そのため難しいのではないかと思っています。

Comment: そういうことなら、まあ最後のは関係無いですね。そのソフトに同様の機能があればとも思いますが、それはそれで使い勝手とか開発コストとか色々課題になるでしょうから。